# Magento - Adding a random product to .../template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add 3 links to random products on the .../template/catalog/product/view.phtml template.

Based on list.phtml, I tried adding:

```
<?php
  $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  foreach ($_productCollection as $_randomProduct) {
    echo $_randomProduct->getProductUrl();
  }
?>
```

But I'm not getting a list back of URL's.  How can I get an array of other product's links and images?

Comment: the magento data object is support syntax 'RAND()' .
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('rand());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code lets you down because `$this` in view.phtml is not the same `$this` as in list.phtml.
If you wanted to get some products relevant to the current product's category try this:

```
$_productCollection = $_product->getCategory()->getProductCollection();
```

Alternatively if you didn't care where they come from:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
```

To get the randomness this little trick will help:

```
$_productCollection->setPageSize(3)
    ->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
```

Now you can use the collection in a foreach loop.