# how can i show prodcts by their attribute in product details page in magento

Tags: magento

In my site home page, I have three blocks like Recommend product,Top ten product and Talking about product, All products are coming properly by their attribute name.For this, I create three attribute in admin section and add layout design in home page in admin section and add block type in page.xml and i call this blocks by their name in 2column-left.phtml

```
 echo $this->getChilidHtml("block_names")
```

But,My problem is when i click on any product it will redirect to product details page that is *catlog/product/view.phtml*, on this page i want to add two different blocks as like home page ,I found its xml page also , I think that is catalog.xml on this page make changes in side the content reference  and it is coming ,but i want to add a new block as line content , i was trying but i am not getting any idea please any solution for this.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="recommend">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product_list" as="recommend_list" template="catalog/product/view/recommend.phtml">
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

I add above line code in catalog.xml as a new block and call it in view.phtml as   **echo $this->getChildHtml('recommend')**  but it is not showing,I am sure this approach is wrong one .

any solution for this how can i call.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please, don't try to add code in comments.  If you have to add code... and I don't mean a **ton** but the minimal required to illustrate your issue, then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,In your catalog.xml

```
   <catalog_product_view translate="label">// find this line 

    <reference name="content">
     ..............

     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

      <block type="catalog/product_list" name="catalog.product_list" as="recommend_list" template="catalog/product/view/recommend.phtml"/> //add your block into product.info block


     .............

     </block>
</reference>
    ................

    </catalog_product_view>
```

call the your block using name  in in catalog/product/view.phtml

**echo $this->getChildHtml('recommend_list')**

Hope this helps

Comment: @clockworkgeek Hi clockworkgeek i got some thing from this post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602712/magento-adding-a-random-product-to-template-catalog-product-view-phtml[/link].

Comment: @clockworkgeek my question is can i call the list.phtml inside the view.phtml

Comment: @clockworkgeek i adding this line of code in Catalog.xml but it is not correct one its coming wrong <reference name="content">
  
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"><block type="catalog/product_list" name="product.info.list" as="list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block></block></reference>

Comment: @clockworkgeek and i call this in view.phtml by adding this line <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls')?> but it is not coming what i do for this